# Intelligent Mail Barcode Looks Correct When Previewed but Does Not Print

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, barcode-printing

I am trying to set up mail merge to generate envelopes to use Intelligent Mail barcodes. I have the proper codes generated using the USPS Excel add-on. I set up the envelope format with the USPSIMStandard font for the barcode line.  When I preview the results the envelope looks correct. That should mean the font for the barcode is working correctly. The problem arises when I try to print the envelope. Everything looks correct except the barcode is missing. It appears there is a space where the barcode should be. Does anyone have any suggestions what might be wrong or what I should check? TIA.

Comment: How many different printers have you checked it out with? Is this a network / shared printer or directly connected?

Comment: 2 printers directly connected. One printer is directly connected but hosted as a network printer so I would not think that is a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh! I should have known. It is working now. In typical MS fashion a reboot cured the problem.